# Posting code using the <pre><code> tags

Tags: discussion, support, questions

This seems to be rather annoying to me. Sometimes it is desirable to format code using the `<pre><code>` tags, i.e.:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

However, this will (sometimes) result in a "Your code is not properly formatted" error, not allowing me to submit it. Is it by design to not allow code to be submitted using the `<pre><code>` tags?

Comment: Is there any reason why you prefer this method to the markdown one of indenting the code?

Comment: I'm unable to view the markdown here, so I can't tell what you did.  But `<code>text</code>` is equivalent to `\`text\`` (producing `text`) and `<pre>text</pre>` is equivelant to `:    text` (on a new line; without the colon (formatting stupidity)).  If you use both it's unnecessary.  (For what you are doing, you only want `<pre>text</pre>`.

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues with using `<pre>` for formatting code.  In particular, things that *look* like html tags become such.  `<iostream>` doesn't format right at all when within a code block.

Furthermore, the code isn't syntax highlighted when in a `<pre>` block.  Note the syntax highlighting here using the four space indent (and a hint that it is C since its not tagged that way):

```C
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

There are *very* few use cases where one would desire to use a `<pre>` block to identify code (though I'm open to being corrected here).

---

And just for 'fun', since it messes up the formatting, this is what the code gets when wrapped in `<pre><code>` tags:

```
#include 

int main()
{
    std::cout
```

Yep, its all there, though its still problematic.

Additional back ticks cause problems when trying to show you that <iostream> isn't showing up in that code block.  The source for the first revision of this post can be seen at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/02b3d1c8-ffed-4453-91b7-aac8e3d033e8/view-source

Comment: Nice how doing that totally scrambles the markup.

Comment: @Deduplicator its a mess.  I would *never* suggest that for anything that even resembles code.  The thing is when you are working with `<pre>`, you need to switch mindset and write html with all its `&gt;` and `&amp;` beauty rather than markdown.

Comment: I use `<pre>` blocks when I want to highlight a part of the code, or otherwise style a quoted section, eg: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/25420815/3478852>. See also: <http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64595/267666>.