# Links to codepen.io not allowed when code is in <pre> tags

Tags: bug, edits

I was editing someone's question to make a link to https://codepen.io clickable. However, the editor did not allow me to make the link clickable with the following error:

[image]

"Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code", even though there was a big chunk of preformatted code immediately following the link. It looks like this restriction doesn't recognize code within the "<pre>" tags, because once I removed the tags, the eror went away, even though the code always had 4 spaces:

[image]

[This is the revision in question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52891437/revisions). Is this a bug, or is there a special way to handle this with "<pre>" tags?

Comment: When the checker sees the `<pre>` tag, it doesn't know that what follows is code; it could just be text the user wanted to be monospace. BTW, Markdown code blocks (i.e. those indented by 4 spaces) are rendered with `<pre><code> ... </code></pre>` tags already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text inside "pre" tags is not considered code - converting such incorrectly formatted text into proper one with 4 (or 8 for lists) spaces is the right action.

Why: in part because `<pre>` may not represent all code correctly, in particular anything with `<…>` will be formatted incorrectly at best - [Posting code using the <pre><code> tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274326/posting-code-using-the-precode-tags).